# Prim's Algorithm using Priority Queue

Tags: c, algorithm, prims-algorithm

New here and need your help. We were asked to use a priority queue and heap for Prim's algorithm and I am stuck. I know it's the shiftUp() function messing up, causing the house of cards of a program to fall down faster than the price of Coca-Cola, but I cannot put a finger on the problem.
Here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10000
typedef struct priority
{
    int edge_1st;
    int edge_2nd;
    int arr[MAX];

}pq;
pq ptr;
int insert(int);
int counter[MAX],size,cost;
void primoperate();
int extract();
int shiftUp(int);
int shiftDown(int);
int parent(int);
int leftChild(int);
int rightChild(int);
int main()
{
    int limit,add,input,j;
    printf("Enter the number of elements you want to enter");
    scanf("%d",&limit);
    for (int i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        printf("1st edge connected");
        scanf("%d",&ptr.edge_1st);
        printf("2nd edge connected");
        scanf("%d",&ptr.edge_2nd);
        printf("Weight of the edge");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        insert(input);
    }
    while(j<=size)
    {
        if ((counter[ptr.edge_1st]||counter[ptr.edge_2nd])!=1)
        {
            add=extract();
            printf("%d",add);
            cost+=add;
            counter[ptr.edge_1st]=counter[ptr.edge_2nd]=1;
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf("The total cost incurred after adding the weights is %d" ,cost);
}
int insert(int input)
{
    size+=1;
    ptr.arr[size]=input;
    shiftUp(size);
    printf("Added %d to the priority queue",input);
    return 0;
}
int shiftUp(int i)
{
    int temporary;
    while(i>0 && ptr.arr[parent(i)]>ptr.arr[i])
    {
        temporary=ptr.arr[parent(i)];
        ptr.arr[parent(i)]=ptr.arr[i];
        ptr.arr[i]=temporary;
        i=parent(i);
        }   
}
int parent(int i)
{
    return(i-1)/2;
}
int leftChild(int i)
{
    return ((2*i)+1);
}
int rightChild(int i)
{
    return ((2*i)+2);
}
int extract()
{
    int result=ptr.arr[0];
    printf("The topmost element in the priority queue at present is: %d",result);
    ptr.arr[0]=ptr.arr[size];
    shiftDown(0);
    return result;  
}
int shiftDown(int i)
{
    int temp=0;
    int minIndex=i;
    int left=leftChild(i);
    if(left<=size && ptr.arr[left]<ptr.arr[minIndex])
    {
        minIndex=left;
    }
    int right=rightChild(i);
    if (right <= size && ptr.arr[right] < ptr.arr[minIndex]) 
    {
        minIndex=right;
    }
    if (i != minIndex) 
    {
        temp=ptr.arr[i];
        ptr.arr[i]=ptr.arr[minIndex];
        ptr.arr[minIndex]=temp;
        shiftDown(minIndex);
    }
    
}
```

I know it's pretty bad and not up to your standards and all, but for my assignment, I badly need your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly would a priority queue solve and how are you supposed to use it? One per node or one for the whole graph?

Comment: Hmmm `parent(), leftChild(), rightChild()` look off by 1.  Is the top parent at `.arr[0]` or `.arr[1]`?

Comment: Lundin,the priority queue is for the latter. The purpose of the priority queue,in my opinion,is to find the minimum,shift it up to the root,and then extract it till nothing's left.

Comment: The top parent would be at index 0.